# Python look for matching in lists

Tags: python, list, pattern-matching, comparison

Say there's a list called `PatternList = ['b', 0, 'e', 0]`. How can I check if in another list, `CompareList = ['r', 't', 'y', 'b', 'i', 'e', 'y', 'b', 't', 'e', 'r', 't', 'b', 'w', 't', 'e']`, is included the pattern contained in `PatternList`, and how many times?

In this case the result would be 2, as CompareList = ['r', 't', 'y', **'b'**, 'i', **'e''**, y, **'b'**, t, **'e'**, 'r', 't', 'b', 'w', 't', 'e'].

Note: PatternList could be read as 'b', any character, 'e', any character.

Comment: im not sure anyone knows what youre asking for, because you are saying you want to see if the pattern is in the second list but then it looks like you want if any of the values appear in the second list

Comment: 0 means any character ? what if the `PatternList = ['b', 'i', 'b', 't' ]` ?

Comment: Do the elements of your pattern and compare lists always consist of single characters? Right now, your sample code isn't even valid Python, so it's hard to guess what you're actually looking for.

Comment: @dnit13 yes, 0 means any character, but a single one. With that second Patternlist, there would be no matches in my CompareList

Comment: According to a comment below, your actual problem is very much different from the trivialized case you posted. Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - as well as any attempts you've made yourself, so we can tell where exactly you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this with regex:

```
import re

l = ["b", "0", "e", "0"]
cl = ["r", "t", "y", "b", "i", "e", "y", "b", "t", "e", "r", "t", "b", "w", "t", "e"]

print re.findall(''.join(l).replace('0','.'), ''.join(cl))
print len(re.findall(''.join(l).replace('0','.'), ''.join(cl)))
```

Output:

```
['biey', 'bter']
2
```

Idea:

1. Join the elements in `l` and replace `0` with `.` to match any character in `cl`.
2. Join the elements in `cl`.
3. Do `re.findall(res_of_step1, res_step_2)`

Comment: Yours is slightly different, considering 0's as int. You can also do `''.join(map(str, a)).replace('0','.')`

Comment: @MYGz this look pretty good, but i get this error: "AssertionError: sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups". Is there a workaround?

Comment: hmm.. We aren't using any groups here. Can you include full error traceback? Or perhaps your pattern list have `(`, `)` in them. If there are any brackets, you will have to escape them in the pattern list.

Comment: @MYGz that's rigth. I'm working with a list of tuples, were each tuple is a pixel in a image (R,G,B,A). My real RefList looks something like [(0, 0, 0, 0), (206, 207, 207, 255),  (204, 204, 204, 255), (0, 0, 0, 0)]. Were RefList[1] will return  (206, 207, 207, 255)

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should ask the problem with full context. Edit your question with clear explanation and mention your goal along with what you have tried if you have.

Answer (score 1):

This looks quite simple when you convert this to regex:

```
a=['b', 0, 'e', 0]
a1 = ['.' if i==0 else i for i in a]
>>> a1
['b', '.', 'e', '.']
>>> a2 = ''.join(a1)
compareList = ['r', 't', 'y', 'b', 'i', 'e', 'y', 'b', 't', 'e', 'r', 't', 'b', 'w', 't', 'e']
>>> compare_string=''.join(compareList)
>>> len(re.findall(a2, compare_string))
2
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you had in mind? You can use list comprehensions:

```
    >>> x = [1,2,3]
    >>> y = [0,2,5,7,4,3]
    >>> [i for i in x if i in y]
    [2, 3]
```

Edit:

```
>>> len(set([i for i in x if i in y]))
2
>>>
```